# Alocar caixa de pesquisa na Navbar padrão do Bootstrap

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-3

Estou com dificuldades em alocar uma caixa de pesquisa no bootstrap. Estou tentando alocá-lo na `navbar` padrão, na parte superior alinhado a direita. Minha intenção é que a cada tela, eu possa modificar os parâmetros para o campo funcionar com cada de tipo de procura como: produto, categoria.

Minha View `Index` de Categoria

```
<div class="navbar navbar-header navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <div class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <form role="search" class="navbar-form">
                <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Procurar" />
                    <span class="form-control-feedback glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Deste jeito, eu não consigo usar os outros "botões" da `navbar` padrão do bootstrap.

Estou usando *ASP .NET MVC* com Bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia amigo, não sei se entendi muito bem o seu problema.

Você quer usar os botões, inclusive com a opção de *collapse* do lado esquerdo e a caixa de pesquisa do lado direito da *navbar*?

Se for isso, segue um exemplo. Eu usei um trecho de código dos tutoriais do W3schools e inseri sua caixa de pesquisa nele. Veja:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <form role="search" class="navbar-form">
                <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Procurar" />
                    <span class="form-control-feedback glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                </div>
            </form>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Espero ter ajudado. Qualquer dúvida retorne.

Mais informações:

http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_navbar.asp
http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda, mas não é isso que quero. Como estou usando o Asp net, esse codigo que vc mandou iria ficar no _Layout.cshtml. Eu queria mesmo poder colocar esta caixa de pesquisa usando uma outra view.